# Trimming Name of a result set - powerhsell

Tags: powershell

```
   $s = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') servername 
   $dbs=$s.Databases #| Out-File E:\Powershell\Output\dbs.txt
   $dbs | select parent
```

The output is [servername] but i want to see only servername. How to remove [] from the string.

Comment: can you post a couple of lines from `$dbs` or is it just one string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `$s.Databases` is the string? Well, wherever it is, you simply need to use `-replace ""`.

You can create a character match group, and then escape the two you need (since they are characters used to create match groups).

You essentially are saying `$x = $string -replace '[' -replace ']'`. When replace has one parameter, it replaces the string with nothing. So you are replacing both "[" and "]" with nothing.

You can combine the two replace statements by creating the match group, using two brackets [], and replace will remove anything inside the contents. You also need to escape your brackets now, since they could close the match group. Now, your replace parameter should look like this:

`-replace '[\[\]]'`

Try this:

```
$s = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') servername 
$dbs = $s.Databases -replace '[\[\]]'
$dbs
```